# Jenkins -- How to vary maven goal depending on build trigger?

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, jenkins-plugins

I would like to introduce Continuous Integration.

After a couple of days I came up with following set up/strategy for my maven projects:

every 5 Minutes jenkins should run

> mvn clean test  //in order to find obvious errors and provide quick feedback

on monday til friday on 8 o'clock and 13 o'clock jenkins should run

> mvn clean integration-test  //more comprehensive testing

on every second friday at 18 o'clock jenkins should run

> mvn clean integration-test verify deploy  //assume everything is great and throw it to the production environment

I can achieve this if I provide 3 Jenkins Jobs per maven project e.g. projXY-unit-test-build, projXY-it-build, projXY-release-build. However this might end up in configuration madness.

Is there an easy way to configure this in one jenkins job? Plus. If you think the whole set up is utter nonsense. Could you provide improvements or other strategies?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you use any version control system? In this case you may trigger frequent tests only when there are some new commits. Also (in my version of Jenkins) I can setup both checking SCM and periodical builds simultaneously, so you can setup both approaches in one job. But I'd prefer only SCM checks (if integration tests are not very "heavy")

Comment: In our environment we have several Jenkins servers and hundreds of jobs. Particularly, our project has 12 dependent jobs which check SCM every hour for changes. These jobs make "mvn install". And for nightly builds we have a separate job which deploy new snapshot on a dev server.

Comment: We use subversion. The every-5-minute-trigger is a check against the repository. The other both are time controlled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Option 1

Use [**Conditional Build Step**](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Conditional+BuildStep+Plugin) plugin with [**Run Condition Extras**](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Run+Condition+Extras+Plugin) plugins to setup the build just as you described, with multiple *"if...then"* conditions.

### Option 2

Setup 3 jobs, each with their own triggers and goals, but [**Shared Workspace**](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Shared+workspace+plugin) between them.